# A faint instagram-shaped beige overlay, always

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

I got a Galaxy S5 (second hand you may note,  however it's in great condition) very recently.
I've noticed that there is a very faint beige-yellow tint on the screen at all times in the shape of the main features of the instagram app.
It's far more obvious on a white background.
Does anybody know why this has happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described, it's very likely that your S5 is the victim of [screen burn-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in). The previous owner likely used Instagram a lot, which burnt the main interface into the screen. The damage is done to the AMOLED screen itself instead of software-based, and thus can't be reverted, unless you decide to replace the screen altogether.

Comment: I have a 2-year warranty, but how much would a screen replacement cost?

Comment: @JacobGarby Free if it is covered by warranty. Is it?

Comment: I think this phenomenon isn't included in warranties anyway. AMOLED screens are always quite expensive - my local resellers have framed ones for ~$100. Customer service might ask a lot more than that.

Comment: @SarpSTA I'd have to ask. I sure hope so

Comment: @JacobGarby What country are you from?

Comment: @SarpSTA England

Comment: @JacobGarby If EU laws are still in effect, as far as I know, it is covered in warranty due 1999/44/EC.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your mobile has had a screen ***damage***. You will need to ***change*** the screen because this is not a ***software*** issue. It's from ***within*** the screen of the phone,and must be changed for a better look.